# Web Scraping - VBA Search Parameters Not Working Properly

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I am working on a web scraping project which would scrape ticketing information off a travel website.

I am currently encountering an issue where the search parameters defined in my VBA code and later input into the website to be executed is not working. The code that has been written is provided below. To provide some background, I am reading in the to/from destinations from my Excel workbook (e.g. Beijing(北京）) and defining the travel date in the same format (MM-DD-YYYY) as the website would expect it to be input. However, when running, the site does not seem to recognize the parameters and directs me to a page saying "*site under maintenance*". The odd thing is, when I manually input the parameters, the site recognizes it and provides ticketing information.

***Am I perhaps missing something? Do I have to update other values outside of "DepartureCity", "ArrivalCity", and "DepartDate"?***

I also noticed that when I loop through multiple cities, the site searches for the same parameters as previously defined (i.e. if searching Shanghai -> Beijing, it yields Tianjin -> Beijing which I had previously searched for). ***Is there a way to auto remove the search history/cache via VBA?***

```
' save from and to destinations under a defined string
sFrom = Range("C3").Value
sTo = Range("C4").Value

' "i" to track the # of days out as defined by the user
For i = 0 To cntDays
    dtRange = Date + i

    ' establish date to pull train ticketing information on
    If Len(Day(dtRange)) = 1 Then
        sDay = "0" & Day(dtRange)
    Else:
        sDay = Day(dtRange)
    End If

    If Len(Month(dtRange)) = 1 Then
        sMonth = "0" & Month(dtRange)
    Else:
        sMonth = Month(dtRange)
    End If

    sDate = sMonth & "-" & sDay & "-" & Year(dtRange)

    ' instantiate the oIE object
    Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ' open Ctrip travel portal
    sURL = "http://english.ctrip.com/trains/#ctm_ref=nb_tn_top"
    With oIE
        .navigate sURL
        .Visible = True

        Do Until (.readyState = 4 And Not .Busy)
           DoEvents
        Loop

        ' search for particular entry
        .document.getElementsByName("DepartureCity")(0).Value = sFrom
        .document.getElementsByName("ArrivalCity")(0).Value = sTo
        .document.getElementsByName("DepartDate")(0).Value = sDate

        MsgBox sFrom
        MsgBox sTo
        MsgBox sDate

        Set ElementCol = .document.getElementsByTagName("button")
            For Each btnInput In ElementCol
                If btnInput.innerText = "Search" Then
                    btnInput.Click
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next btnInput

        ' ensure page has been fully loaded
        Do Until (.readyState = 4 And Not .Busy)
           DoEvents
        Loop
```

Comment: looking at the source of the url provided, there are hidden input fields just below the search button. Try using those instead. From the source... `<input id="DepartureCityPinyin" type="hidden" name="DepartureCityPinyin">`

Comment: So rather than '.document.getElementsByName("DepartureCity")(0).Value = sFrom' you are recommending that I use '.document.getElementsByName("DepartureCityPinyin")(0).Value = sFrom' instead?

Comment: yes, or try setting both...

Comment: Just tried that and doesn't work. Same issue arises where it leads me to a page that says "page under maintenance...try again later", but once I manually input the parameters it works and gives me ticketing information. It seems like you have to choose from the dropdown values...

Not entirely sure what's going on here. Baffled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this a little closer, the site uses a GET request to perform the search.
As such, there is no need to load the page, populate the fields, and click the button.
You can set the values in the URL directly and bypass the initial page.

For instance, to search for trains going from Shanghai to Beijing on 12-9-2015, load the following URL...

http://english.ctrip.com/trains/List/Index?DepartureCity=shanghai%28%E4%B8%8A%E6%B5%B7%29&ArrivalCity=beijing%28%E5%8C%97%E4%BA%AC%29&DepartDate=12-9-2015&DepartureStation=%E4%B8%8A%E6%B5%B7&ArrivalStation=%E5%8C%97%E4%BA%AC

When broken down looks like this...

> http://english.ctrip.com/trains/List/Index?
>   DepartureCity=shanghai%28%E4%B8%8A%E6%B5%B7%29
>   ArrivalCity=beijing%28%E5%8C%97%E4%BA%AC%29
>   DepartDate=12-9-2015
>   DepartureStation=%E4%B8%8A%E6%B5%B7
>   ArrivalStation=%E5%8C%97%E4%BA%AC

From my own testing, I've determined that each of the above fields are required or you get the "maintenance" screen...

Which means you need to know the station codes as well.

In addition you must supply the special characters in the names...

`shanghai%28%E4%B8%8A%E6%B5%B7%29`

Comment: hope this helps, you could perform searches manually to determine the station codes you need...

Comment: WhiteHat - It doesn't seem to work. When I replace the DepartureCity within the URL directly it still reverts to the previous search results that had been properly searched within the home screen.

Comment: I think I got it, each city has its own unique set of special characters