# VBA Web Scraper- Web page reverting back to the first search parameters after inputting new ones

Tags: excel, vba, search, web-scraping

This is a follow up to a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53108817/vba-web-scraper-having-trouble-activating-a-search-button-via-click). I finished creating the scraper that grabs age and address based on first/last name and city/state into the web site [www.healthgrades.com](https://www.healthgrades.com/). What's really strange is that no matter what I input via the macro and search, it reverts to a name and city/state that I ran tests with. I tried clearing the cookies and cache but that didn't work. Is this a normal issue with web scrapers that input search parameters?

I don't think this has anything to do with my code unless there's a clear history/cache command I should use, but here is my code:

```
Sub HGScrape()

    Const sURL As String = "https://www.healthgrades.com/"

    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    Dim loop_ctr As Integer

    With ie

        .Visible = False
        .Navigate sURL
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        .document.getElementById("search-term-selector-child"). _
                    Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
        .document.getElementById("search-location-selector-child"). _
                    Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B2")
        .document.getElementsByClassName("submiter__text")(0).Click
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value = .document.getElementsByClassName("uCard__age")(0).innerText
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Value = .document.getElementsByClassName("address--street")(0).innerText
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        ActiveSheet.Range("E2").Value = .document.getElementsByClassName("address--city-state")(0).innerText

        For loop_ctr = 3 To 10

            .document.getElementById("uSearch-search-term-selector-child"). _
                        Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & loop_ctr)
            .document.getElementById("uSearch-search-location-selector-child"). _
                        Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & loop_ctr)
            .document.getElementsByClassName("submiter__text")(0).Click
            While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            ActiveSheet.Range("C" & loop_ctr).Value = .document.getElementsByClassName("uCard__age")(0).innerText
            While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            ActiveSheet.Range("D" & loop_ctr).Value = .document.getElementsByClassName("address--street")(0).innerText
            While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            ActiveSheet.Range("E" & loop_ctr).Value = .document.getElementsByClassName("address--city-state")(0).innerText
            While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Next loop_ctr

    End With

    Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: EU is denied access apparently. How rude  ;-)

Comment: You don't need all those  While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend  in betweeen setting values.

Comment: What does _reverts to a name and city/state that I ran tests with_ mean? Did you manually enter info and this is what is remembered despite what you input via vba?

Comment: Inside your loop you're using the same input values (A3 and B3) for each iteration, but putting the outputs on different lines.  Did you really mean to do that?

Comment: @QHarr regarding your question, you are correct. Yesterday I ran scrape and loop tests with one name and city, state. Today it will only search that name and city, state despite a new browser instance, and taking that test name completely out of my spreadsheet.

Comment: @TimWilliams, that was an error when copying into the post. I edited the post to put the dynamic loop_ctr cell reference in there.

Comment: One option might be to use selenium basic wrapper for vba. That tends not to remember any prior conditions. Are you sure you haven't set any defaults e.g. a home city, state? Your tests yesterday were automated not manual i.e. the ones that are remembered?

Comment: @QHarr I'll check that out. Yep, all tests were done via the macro with spreadsheet references. Really weird stuff. Luckily, it looks like I can use a dynamic URL to bypass the search button thanks to a linked post on this one. I'm going to rewrite and see if that solves my issue. [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156412/web-scraping-vba-search-parameters-not-working-properly?rq=1)

Comment: If a queryString (which I am guessing is what you dynamic URL might be?) is available you might be able to use XHR as well as IE. Does your dynamic URL have the city etc concatenated into it?  For the next 6 months (until we do our stupid Brexit number - :rant:) I cannot access site so can't test.

Comment: @QHarr I can't imagine what UK is like right now with Brexit and the recent anti-meme regulations. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to adjust the URL and skip the input/search process thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156412/web-scraping-vba-search-parameters-not-working-properly?rq=1). The actual scraping section started throwing errors because it was trying to scrape before the site had loaded fully so I peppered in the `while .busy or .readystate < 4` but that wasn't working correctly so I also added in an `Application.Wait` command as well. Not sure if that was the most efficient way to handle the site lag but as long as I get this work done within a reasonable amount of time, it's fine for me. Spreadsheet URL formula and VBA code below:

`="https://www.healthgrades.com/usearch?what="&H2&"%20"&J2&"&where="&M2&"%2C%20"&N2&"&pageNum=1&isStandalone=true&city="&M2&"&state="&N2`

```
Sub HGScrape2()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim loop_ctr As Integer
Dim sURL As String

With ie

For loop_ctr = 2 To 637

sURL = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & loop_ctr).Value

    .Visible = False
    .Navigate sURL

    While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5"))
    ActiveSheet.Range("C" & loop_ctr).Value = .document.getElementsByClassName("uCard__age")(0).innerText
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    ActiveSheet.Range("D" & loop_ctr).Value = .document.getElementsByClassName("address--street")(0).innerText
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    ActiveSheet.Range("E" & loop_ctr).Value = .document.getElementsByClassName("address--city-state")(0).innerText
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

Next loop_ctr

End With

End Sub
```